# Class Exists Check Comparison

Tags: php, comparison

Is there a diference between this comparisons ?
What is the diference between ! and === FALSE ?

```
if (!class_exists($class)) {
  require($class.'.php');
}

if (class_exists($class) === FALSE) {
  require($class.'.php');
}
```

Comment: In this case, nothing as `class_exists()` will only return a boolean. See the note on [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) for a description of when you might need to use `=== false`

Comment: So I can use any of this for class_exists() then ?

Comment: Yes, either test will yield the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, no.

Some people think it's good programming style to explicitly show that they're comparing to a boolean. Personally... I don't like it, but I guess the more verbose form is more obvious, as the ! operator isnt the mose visible thing when smashed between a parenthesis and other vertically'ish characters.

Comment: Actually I find it better to use ! then === FALSE, just did not know the diference. Thank you guys.

Answer (score -1):

Yes both are the different things:

php automatically considers 0 as "false" and 1 as "true" so when ever you use function response directly inside the if condition at that this both makes a difference.

consider a function, if executed properly at that it returns int number. it may be 0 too.
But if function did not match requirement at that it is returning false.

So at this time function returning value 0 is success. event though the result is zero. At this if you check this in if condition like

```
$return = someFunction();

if($return){
  //code if ture
}
```

so if $return is 0 your if code will not be executed even your function execution was correct so in that case you should check like

```
$return = someFunction();

if($return !== FALSE){
  //code if ture
}
```

=== and !== are used to check the response exactly match return type also.

```
if('0' === 0)
```

will return false
but

```
if('0' == 0)
```

will return true...

Hope your idea is clear now.

check this out:

```
if('0' == 0){
    echo 'Hi, I will be in screen :)';
}

if('0' === 0){
    echo 'I will not be in screen :(';
}
```